# Substring not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have a table in MySQL from which I'm extracting the first letter and inserting it into another column which is empty but its not extracting properly. Its showing null values and doubling the no of rows in the table and showing it in the other half like below.

```
TEAM              TS

AUSTRALIA         (NULL)
ZIMBABWE          (NULL)
GHANA             (NULL)
(NULL)             A
(NULL)             Z
(NULL)             G
```

But I want it in the following manner:

```
TEAM              TS

AUSTRALIA         A
ZIMBABWE          Z
GHANA             G
```

I have written the following query:

```
insert into [table_name]
 (
 TS
 ) 
 SELECT  SUBSTRING(TEAM,1,1)   
     FROM [table_name]
;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `update`.  I would write this as:

```
update table_name
    set ts = left(team, 1);
```

`insert` inserts new rows.  `update` changes the values in existing rows.  That is why you are getting additional rows with `NULL` values for the `team`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Add a new entry in table, and you specify TS column only, so the team column takes null value.
You should use UPDATE :

```
UPDATE [table_name]
SET table_name.TS = (SELECT  SUBSTRING(B.TEAM,1,1)   
 FROM (SELECT TEAM FROM [table_name]) AS B))
```

Comment: ""You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause ""